# LU Decomposition - Are there multiple ways to calculate?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, matrix-decomposition

I am attempting to use LU Decomposition to calculate the determinant of a matrix. Given:

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\ 
5 & 6
\end{pmatrix}
$$

When using this calculator: [Here](http://www.bluebit.gr/matrix-calculator/calculate.aspx) the values give me:

$$
L = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 
0.2 & 1.0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
U = \begin{pmatrix}
5.00 & 6.00 \\ 
0.00 & 0.800
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I'm using an algorithm, and, they give the values as:

$$
L = \begin{pmatrix}
1.00 & 0.0 \\ 
5.00 & -4.0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
U = \begin{pmatrix}
1.00 & 2.0 \\ 
0.0 & 1.0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Screen shot from calculator:

[image]

From my understanding, from reading previous papers and journals that, the the lower matrix should contain all "1" values down the diagonal?

Also, why are the two methods returning different values, yet, they both return the same determinant?

Comment: Hint: multiply the first two matrices. What do you get?

Comment: @symplectomorphic - I'm somewhat missing the point, how do you mean? Which matrices? Please could you provide an example?

Comment: do the obvious thing and check the factorizations by multiplying the L and U from each source. You will see the first factorization is wrong. You switched the rows.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Done this. Thanks. Check my updated post, I have included a screen shot of the calculate that I'm using. As you can see, the values are entered the same so why is it switching the rows?

Comment: It's using a permutation matrix, when one isn't needed. I don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

"The" LU Decomposition of a matrix is, as you can see, not unique, usually there are multiple LU Decompositions. Of course they all have the same determinant, because if $A=LU=L'U'$, then $\det(A)=\det(LU)=\det(L'U')$. I don't think it is commonly required, that there are only $1$'s on $L$'s diagonal.

Comment: Ohh, okay thank you! So both answers therefore are technically correct?

Comment: Should be. BUT in your case, I think you switched the rows of $A$ (when using a calculator), if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: No I did not switch the rows. I entered the values exactly the same into the calculator. I don't think the algorithm is switching rows either. I know that the calculator uses a Permutation matrix, but I don't think the calculator does. I assume that this is the right result?

Comment: Yeah, you should have mentoined that, initially. In that case, with $PA = LU$ ($P$ being said permutation matrix) it is indeed correct.